# Centering UIWebView content with padding

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a UIView which loads a html5 banner. I get padding on each side of the banner which is to be expected since the banners width is shorter than the UIWebView. However.. The padding on each side is a lot bigger than I should get.

I just want the banner to be centered if the banner is shorter than the UIWebView.

Instead of looking like this: (Where X is banner and O is padding)

|OOXXXXXXOO|

It looks like this:

|OOOOXXXXXX|

Here, if I enable scrolling I can center it like the first example.

How do I fix this?

**Code**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bannerIdentifier];

if (!cell) {

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"bannerCell"];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, cell.contentView.bounds.size.height)];
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/page.html"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[cell.contentView addSubview:webView];

}
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to design the webpage to be more flexible.  Are you using a fixed width for the banner's container?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is UIWebView shows HTML, that means, that if your HTML has to be rendered as you wish - the only correct way to achieve this is to fix loaded HTML (and or css).
You can do it in several ways:

1. If you have access to the HTML data on server you could tweak it to be rendered correctly in UIWebView.
2. If you don't have access to the HTML data on server you could use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: and fix desired elements in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to query the DOM for the width of the desired element using Javascript. You can then resize the webview to fit that size.

This gives you the width:
`document.getElementById('YOURID').offsetWidth;`